# Insert string to div on button click and clear it before next click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to create function which after click button, get string from user (from input) and spell it into div. It works, but only one time. When I change the string and click another one to button, page remember previous entered string. 
I have tried to clear div and array before new iterating, but without success.

```
button.addEventListener('click', spell);

function spell(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newArr = [];

    for (let i=0; i<userText.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(userText[i]);
    }
    programText.textContent = newArr;
}
```

How to clear an array to avoid this problem?

Comment: where/how is `userText` populated - you could add `userText.length = 0` after the `for` loop to clear it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a complete example for us to debug. This has to include enough to replicate the functionality instead of the community having to guess at what your data, or what any other parts of code, looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I have to only delete value from let userText = document.querySelector('.userText'); and enter value to body of function. The correct version, below.
Thank you everybody for help :)

```
   const button = document.querySelector('.button');
let userText = document.querySelector('.userText');
let programText = document.querySelector('.programText');


button.addEventListener('click', spell); 

function spell(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i=0; i<userText.value.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(userText.value[i]);
    }
    programText.textContent = newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear `userText` after you spell it, you can use `userText.length = 0`:

```
function spell(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i=0; i<userText.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(userText[i]);
    }
    userText.length = 0;
    programText.textContent = newArr;
}
```

You don't even need to copy `userText` into `newArr`:

```
function spell(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    programText.textContent = userText;
    userText.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: why would you even need to copy userText -> newArr? seems `spell` could be further simplified by just `programText.textContent = userText;` and then clearing userText

Comment: Because I want to spell userText in programText --> "String" --> s,t,r,i,n,g

Comment: Mayby I wrong descibe my target :) I want prompt by user to userText new string, spell it and enter spelled to programText instead of the old one. Next after click, the same action. Clear programText and spell new string into programText.

Answer (score 0):

Full code to this:
I have tried to clearing an array using: newArray = [] and newArray.length = 0. And clearing programText using programText.textContent = '' and programText.length = 0;

HTML

```
<article class=proj001Up>
            <button class="button">Function 01</button>
            <p>Spell the string</p>
</article>
        <article class="proj001Down">
            <input class="userText" type="text" name="userText" placeholder="Enter your string/word">
            <article class="programText" placeholder="Result"></article>
```

JS

```
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
let userText = document.querySelector('.userText').value;
let programText = document.querySelector('.programText');


button.addEventListener('click', spell); 

function spell(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i=0; i<userText.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(userText[i]);
    }
    programText.textContent = newArr;
}
```